# JavaFX - How to deactivate a comboBox Listener

Tags: java, combobox, javafx

I'm modifying`ComboBox combo1` using a Listener of another `ComboBox combo2`.

`combo1` has a ChangeListener which modifies the content of a `ListView listView`

The problem is: if I change the content of `combo1` using the ChangeListener of `combo2`, I must clear `combo1`, BUT doing this will turn cause null content for a moment, so the `listView` can't be filled and I'll get a `nullPointerException`.

The solution that I could think of is:

1. I deactivate or disable the ChangeListener of `combo1`.
2. I change the value of `combo2` which will modify the items of `combo1` (I suppose that I won't be getting any NPEs because `combo1` has no ChangeListener so it's not observing its content to change the `listView`).
3. Activate `combo1` ChangeListener again (or set it again)

Is there a way to deactivate a ComboBox ChangeListener ?

Comment: Why don't you add a `null check`?

Comment: add a null check ? you mean ? i tried `combo1.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
     @Override public void changed(ObservableValue ov, String t, String t1) {
     
    }
    });` not working :(

Comment: I've run into similar situations like this, and simply remove the listener altogether, do my combo box modification, then add the listener back to the combo box.

Comment: `null` check means you just check if it is `null` before doing anything with it... `if (t1 != null) { ... }`

Comment: @James_D THANKS ! DUDE DONE ! saving me for many times haha, it worked :)